# Multitargetting to metro and non metro target platform in Windows 8

Tags: c#, wpf, windows-8, microsoft-metro, .net-4.5

I am creating a simple metro app. I am also creating non metro version of the same app.

The problem I am facing is that VS is not allowing me to reference normal class libraries into the metro app, and metro class libraries into a normal app.

The differences between Metro and non-metro apps relate to UI, and to some features which are incompatible (eg, FilePicker in metro, and OpenFileDialog in non metro).

How this can be achieved?

Comment: Scratch that off your list of options.  WinRT is different.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The differences are more drastic than you might expect.  They are using WinRT as a chance to clean house and remove APIs they don't want to maintain anymore for various reasons.  Research "portable class library" which will let you create a dll based on the small intersection of APIs available in the platforms you tell VS to target

Comment: Thanks for the information.
I will look to portable class library. You and Hans are absolutely right. Differences are so drastic that it is not advisable to keep common portion between metro app and non metro app

I will check portable class library and decide how to proceed in my case.

Answer (score 0):

Essentially, WinRT is completely separate from the Win32 libraries as Robert Levy mentioned.

In fact, when Windows 8 is being used on ARM devices the Win32 libraries are practically non-existent. Internet Explorer 10 has limited access to them (an Internet browser powered only by WinRT is impractical), but all other metro apps do not.

Metro apps on x86 and x64 also do not have access to Win32, because it is assumed that the same application needs to be compatible with ARM. To reduce complexity Microsoft has essentially said that all metro apps only have access to WinRT. Internet Explorer is an exception to that rule.

What I'm trying to say is this: You'll have to develop both applications separately. Desktop-focused applications reside entirely on the desktop. And metro applications reside only in the metro interface.

Answer (score 0):

Metro UI is not the problem : look "Under the Hood", and you'll discover that the namespaces and the libraries and NOT the same => METRO in NOT another layer above Windows 7 applications.
If you really want to target the 2 environments, create a single class Library with all your business objects, all your databases access, and write two differrents applications call this Library.